# How do I stop a naming clash in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have a service...

```
angular.module('app.services').service('Booking', function () {})
```

In our controller we do this...

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
  .controller('PassengersController',
  function (Booking) {

    Booking.load();
...
```

Which has been fine up until now. However the application is growing and we need to create another 'Booking' object. This object should live under a different namespace to avoid naming clashes as I can't see how angular will inject the right dependency. For example we now need...

```
app.services --> Booking
app.states --> Booking
```

Ideally we would like to refactor our modules to represent the file structure which is now built by feature but trying one thing at a time does anyone know how I can tell angular to access this new booking object explicitly in my controllers?

I was thinking it could be like this....

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
  .controller('PassengersController',
  function (Booking) {

    Booking.load();

    var bookingState = app.states.Booking;
    bookingState.goToNextState();

...
```

Thats ths pseudocode anyway, if it was just pure javascript easy peasy I would just make a global variable and attach some modules but I am not sure how we will do it so we can leverage angularJs's dependency injection and stop the naming clash!

Comment: And it's not possible to call one type `ServiceBooking` and the other `StateBooking`?

Comment: The obvious answer would be that ^. Naming two separate types the same thing, especially when they do different things, is the opposite of verbose.

Comment: @Sippy no it isn't! One is a state, one is a domain object! They are both the same name but the namespace gives them context! This is the whole reason namespaces exist in any language because you may have objects that need to be called the same thing but have different uses.

Comment: @paul why should I? I want to use namepaces like any normal object orientated programmer would. Without going into detail they are both interpretations of the same thing, but one is state and one is a domain object.

Comment: I can see why you'd wanna keep Booking the same as a domain model but I see literally no reason why you can't rename `states.Booking` to `states.BookingState`

Comment: Without going into detail, we are dealing with an app of medium size with a lot of debt, I do not want to refactor the entire thing in one go and need to be able to call the state 'Booking' too if possible.....if it's not possible then fine that's what I want to know....

Comment: How about a service wrapper that has two variables with appropriate and different namings, one for each object you have with the same name, and that way you don't have to refactor the services themselves?

Comment: Sounds like that is what I am going to have to do. I will have to create two modules so that the conflicts can be resolved in the middle. Oh dear angular doesn't lend itself to namespacing as well as just plain old javascript even!

Comment: Well basically if in javascript you'd place it on the window as a global variable, you could do the same with the `$rootScope`, but not very recommended.

Comment: Yeah but then that's just plain old javascript, just so happens I am lobbing it on an angular global variable not my own. I would prefer to use my own in that case and not couple to angular, unless angular is giving me DI with namespacing (which it really should). Angular is ok but like all frameworks they want you to get into bed with them and never leave.